# Workers unable to connect to driver on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark, pyspark

I've got an issue with my Spark cluster. I've got a cluster set up on 3 different ec2 machines and everything is working when trying to submit in there. 
What I'm trying to do is to submit from my Windows 7 machine using Eclipse. 
When I run the Pi.py example locally on Eclipse it works fine. 
I'll show you my code so that it's easier to understand:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
from random import random
from operator import add
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext


if __name__ == "__main__":
"""
    Usage: pi [partitions]
"""
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("spark://52.50.19.132:7077") #"52.50.19.132" is the master's 
# public ip, as the private one didn't allow connection(don't know why...ssh?)
conf.setAppName("PythonPi")
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "500m")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
partitions = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 2
n = 100000 * partitions

def f(_):
    x = random() * 2 - 1
    y = random() * 2 - 1
    return 1 if x ** 2 + y ** 2 < 1 else 0

count = sc.parallelize(range(1, n + 1), partitions).map(f).reduce(add)
print("Pi is roughly %f" % (4.0 * count / n))

sc.stop()
```

When I run this from Eclipse I can connect to the master and I can see from the Spark UI that the application is running. But I keep on getting

```
WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources;
check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

So at the beginning I though it was a problem of ports that were closed and I opened all of them. But nothing changed. 
I thought that it was a problem of ssh connection but I'm actually connected via Putty to the ec2 machines, although **I thought the issue was the other way around, I mean from the ec2 machines to connect to the Windows machine instead.**
I also checked via

```
netstat -an
```

if there was some issues and I found that there is a **SYN_SENT** between the ec2 workers and my Windows machine. 
I hope you can help

Comment: Some job is pending and your scheduler can allocate resources for the new job. Check if there is some hanging jobs !

Comment: On the Spark Ui there is no application waiting or running  and the memory that I allocated for this task is considerably small so it shuldn't block anything!

Comment: I notice that whe I type netstat -an on the master I can see that it is connected to the Windows machine(the host) using the public Ip address(obviously). I would like to "force" the workers to do the same, hence to use the public ip to connect back to the Windows machine(the driver) but I can't find any configuration file to do that.

Comment: You are confusing me ! Is it on EC2 or not ?

Comment: the master and the 2 workers are on 3 different ec2-instances, the driver(where I create the SparkContext from) is my Windows machine.